Momentum operator in infinite well strikes back
I got puzzled by the momentum operator in the infinite well, again. I know it is sort of pathological due to the compact region and I have read the topics about it here. But my question is a bit different from those already answered in this forum.
Consider the particle confined between $0$ and $a$ and initial state $|\psi(0)\rangle =|\phi_n\rangle+|\phi_m\rangle$, where $|\phi_n\rangle$ are stationary eigenstates of the Hamiltonian and $m\neq n$. I want to compute momentum expectation value for all $t$,
$$\langle P\rangle=\langle\psi(0)|U^\dagger PU|\psi(0)\rangle,$$
where $U=e^{-itH/\hbar}$ is the time evolution operator.
If I compute in the Schroedinger picture, I get
$$\langle P\rangle=\left[\langle\psi(0)|U^\dagger \right]P\left[U|\psi(0)\rangle\right]=2\mathrm{Re}\{e^{i(E_n-E_m)t/\hbar}\langle\phi_n|P|\phi_m\rangle\}.$$
But when in the Heisenberg picture, since $\left[P,U\right]=0$, we have
$$\langle P\rangle=\langle\psi(0)|\left[ U^\dagger PU\right]|\psi(0)\rangle=\langle\psi(0)|P|\psi(0)\rangle=2\mathrm{Re}\{\langle\phi_n|P|\phi_m\rangle\}.$$
So the results disagree. However they should be equal, since
$$\left[\langle\psi(0)|U^\dagger \right]A\left[U|\psi(0)\rangle\right]=\langle\psi(0)|\left[ U^\dagger AU\right]|\psi(0)\rangle,$$
for any operator $A$.
How to explain this contradiction?
Edit: I also don't see how saying "there is no momentum operator" in the infinite well potential answer the question. In that case I would reestate the problem by avoiding the word "momentum" and simply saying that $P=-i\hbar d/dx$.

If the $\phi_n$ are energy eigenstates with $E_n\ne E_m$  then then the integrals are zero.  Observe that  $A$ takes  energy eigenfunctions to eigenfunctions of the same energy.

The key point here is that if you assume $[U(t),\hat p]=0$ (which is reasonable since $\hat H\sim \hat p^2$) then you would never get any time dependence for $\langle p\rangle$.  So it must be that $\hat U(t)$ and $\hat p$ cannot be commuted or the commutator is otherwise technically ill-defined because of domain issues and this kind of functional analysis details.

@ZeroTheHero I guess that this commutator is ill-defined for the infinite well. Take for instance $\langle\phi_1| HP|\phi_2\rangle$ and $\langle\phi_1| PH|\phi_2\rangle$. It is easy to show the difference between those two expressions is $(E_2-E_1)8i\hbar /3=E_1 8i\hbar \neq 0$.

@TobiasFünke It is easy to show that you are mistaken. Take this counterexample (easy for you to verify): $\langle\phi_1| HP|\phi_2\rangle - \langle\phi_1| PH|\phi_2\rangle=E_1 8i\hbar \neq 0$. I considered the infinite well between $0$ and $1$ and $H|\phi_n\rangle=E_n|\phi_n\rangle$.

@ZeroTheHero Taking $P:=-id/dx$ with domain of continuously differentiable functions vanishing at the end-points, I think the matrix elements (in the eigenbasis of $H$) of the commutator $[U,P]$ is, in fact, well-defined: $U$ is bounded so this does not cause any problem, and all eigenstates of $H$ (and linear combinations thereof) are in the domain of $P$. The point is, simply, that $U$ and $P$ do not commute: $\langle \phi_n, UP \phi_m\rangle-\langle \phi_n PU\phi_m\rangle=\left( e^{-iE_nt} - e^{-iE_mt}\right) \langle \phi_n, P\phi_m \rangle \neq 0$ in general -- or do I miss something?

@TobiasFünke I think you’re right but why should $U(t)=e^{-i H t/\hbar}$ not commute with $p$ when $H$ is basically $p^2$?  After all, one would naively think that $[H,p]=0$ and so $[U,p]=0$.  I don’t think you’re missing anything, but I think I am missing something…

@ZeroTheHero $H$ is not $P^2$ (keep in mind the domains etc.), $P$ is not self-adjoint to begin with. BTW: I think commutator of $H$ and $P$ is not well-defined on the (dense) subspace of linear combinations of eigenfunctions of $H$, I think, because $P \phi_n$ does not vanish at the end-points. (Actually, everything is even more complicated, because one would work with the self-adjoint extension of $H$, but if I had to guess, I'd say the conclusion is the same).

@TobiasFünke  $H$ is surely $p^2/(2m)$, this by definition, although it may not be the square of $p$, I’ll grant you that.  Presumably this is where domains come in (and all the self-adjoint stuff), in taking the square of p, rather than using $p^2$ right away.

Clearly something’s counterintuitive….

@TobiasFünke So we agree that there is some issue with the commutator between P and U.  But in fact I insist that this issue is originated from the compactness of the space. Yourself pointed out that $P\phi_n$ does not vanish at the endpoints. I would really appreciate if you expand your ideas as an answer, explaining for instance why $H$ is not $P^2$.

@mikestone Actually, If $A$ is the momentum operator, those matrix elements do not vanish because the eigenstate of $H$ are not eigenstate of $P$ for the infinite well.

WP.

@ AI Free. I was addressing the general case, not $A=P$ as $P$ is not an observable. In particular $P^2\ne P P$ for thios reason.

@ZeroTheHero and OP: Yes exactly: With $P^2:=P\circ P$, $\mathcal D(P)$ as described above and $\mathcal D(P^2):=\left{\psi\in \mathcal D(P),\big\lvert, P\psi\in \mathcal D(P)\right}$ you immediately see that $\phi_n\not\in \mathcal D(P^2)$ and thus $H\neq P^2$. OP: I don't see any problem with the commutation relation between $U$ and $P$, but rather with $H$ and $P$ (concerning possible domains). But everything discussed here is, as far as I can see, the usual thing with the infinite square well...

@mikestone Is $P^2\neq PP$ because when one applies $P$ to the wavefunction then the result is no longer a function satisfying the contour conditions? And how one justify that the hamiltonian for the square well is $H=P^2=-d^2/dx^2$? Sorry for so much question, but I really want to understand this problem.

I simply mean that $P^2\stackrel{\rm def}= H$  and $P P$ have different domains, as explained by
Tobias Fünke. Different domains means that they are different opertors. An operator is defined by its "recipe" (i.e $P= i\hbar \partial$ and by its domain.
